# Reverse engineering temperature values

Tags: temperature, conversion

I have a black box, where an input exists for a temperature sensor, which has a 10k NTC connected to it, and I see the following values of the 10k NTC from a log file the black box generates, and a reference value I measured with an electronic sensor:

```
NTC | deg C
886 |  open circuit
860 | -2.6 deg C (ice cube water)
820 | 18
785 | 30
720 | 40
700 | 45
```

I cannot make sense of these values. Is there a way to find the formula to convert the NTC values to deg C? It seems non-linear (if not nonsensical).

Comment: What is 886? Voltage or Resistance of equivalent circuit?

Comment: have u tried to google it?

Comment: How do you "see" the values? Does the box have a display on it of some sort? In any case, you can plug the numbers into a spreadsheet and use its curve-fitting capabilities.

Comment: @Umar: it means: no NTC connected; if I short-circuit it, the value is 136.

Comment: @DaveTweed: it is a black box with a serial interface, spitting out a bunch of values; one is temperature, which ranges from 886 when no NTC is connected to the temp terminal, and 136 when this terminal is short-circuited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a standard NTC thermistor is non-linear.

There are a number of different models used to pull temp info out of a thermistor, depending on how much accuracy you need and how many parameters you want to use.

The simplest is the simple "beta" equation,

$$ \frac{1}{T} = \frac{1}{T_0}+ \frac{1}{\beta}\ln \left ( \frac{R}{R_0}\right) $$

so

$$R = R_0 \exp \left ( -\beta \left (  \frac{1}{T_0} - \frac{1}{T}\right) \right)$$

Thus, you pick a reference \$ T_0\$ at some temperature near your region of interest, and measure the \$R_0\$ associated with it, and measure some other temperature's R, and calculate \$\beta\$.  Then you use that \$\beta\$ for other calculations.   Different temperature points will yield you different calculations of \$\beta\$, as the formula is not exact.  You'll need to figure out your tolerance for errors.

There are more accurate models, like the Steinhart-Hart equations (of which the beta formulation is a simplified case)

I don't know what "open circuit" means in your table, but I don't think it necessarily belongs in your calculations.  I also can't tell how you're measuring the resistance (maybe as a voltage from a divider sampled on an ADC??), and this will have an impact.

Be careful not to pass too much current through a thermistor, as they can self heat.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the NTC's *resistance* in your measurements. Then create a chart of the values. As a start, you could assume that 1) the box outputs values corresponding linearly to input *voltage* and 2) the NTC is sensed via a voltage divider with a constant reference voltage. This is a common design.

$$V_{ntc} = \dfrac{R_{ntc}} {R_{ntc} + R_{internal}} \cdot V_{ref}$$

In the open circuit condition you should be seeing \$V_{ref}\$ across the input pins. Once you have that, it's easy to calculate \$R_{internal}\$ with one more measurement.

Next, check if you can make out a linear relationship between different \$V_{ntc}\$ and output values, like

> "when \$V_{ntc}\$ is X then the output is O[1], when \$V_{ntc}\$ is X+0.5V the output is O[1]+20, and when \$V_{ntc}\$ is X+1.0V the output is O[1]+40"
>   -> linear @ 40 digits per Volt.

If these tests don't show linear dependencies between \$V_{ntc}\$ and the output value, there must be another non-linear element in your box and your best bet is probably to just map many input/output pairs and interpolate between them as needed.